# Java Object Without a Class

Tags: java, object, methods, return-value

I don't know if this is possible in Java but I was wondering if it is possible to use an object in Java to return multiple values without using a class.

Normally when I want to do this in Java I would use the following

```
public class myScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // initialize object class
        cl_Object   lo_Object   = new cl_Object(0, null);

        // populate object with data
        lo_Object = lo_Object.create(1, "test01");
        System.out.println(lo_Object.cl_idno + " - " + lo_Object.cl_desc);

        //
        // code to utilize data here
        //

        // populate object with different data
        lo_Object = lo_Object.create(2, "test02");
        System.out.println(lo_Object.cl_idno + " - " + lo_Object.cl_desc);

        //
        // code to utilize data here
        //

    }

}

// the way I would like to use (even though it's terrible)

class cl_Object {

    int      cl_idno   = 0;
    String   cl_desc   = null;
    String   cl_var01  = null;
    String   cl_var02  = null;

    public cl_Object(int lv_idno, String lv_desc) {
        cl_idno  = lv_idno;
        cl_desc  = lv_desc;
        cl_var01 = "var 01";
        cl_var02 = "var 02";
    }

    public cl_Object create(int lv_idno, String lv_desc) {
        cl_Object   lo_Object   = new cl_Object(lv_idno, lv_desc);
        return lo_Object;
    }

}

// the way I don't really like using because they get terribly long

class Example {

    int      idno = 0;
    String   desc = null;
    String   var01 = null;
    String   var02 = null;

    public void set(int idno, String desc) {
        this.idno = idno;
        this.desc = desc;
        var01     = "var 01";
        var02     = "var 02";
    }

    public int idno() {
        return idno;
    }

    public String desc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public String var01() {
        return var01;
    }

    public String var02() {
        return var02;
    }

}
```

Which seems like a lot of work considering in Javascript (I know they are different) I can achieve the same effect just doing

```
var lo_Object = f_Object();
console.log(lo_Object["idno"] + " - " + lo_Object[desc]);

function f_Object() {

    var lo_Object = {};

    lo_Object = {};
    lo_Object["idno"] = 1;
    lo_Object["desc"] = "test01";

    return lo_Object;

}
```

*NOTE*

I know the naming convention is wrong but it is intentional because I have an informix-4gl program that runs with this program so the coding standards are from the company I work for

Comment: Is there a reason you need the create method? Why not just initialize it with correct values? Or do you want to be able to change the values? In that case you could just use a set method to set the values of the object, and not make a constructor.

Comment: Please, follow Java's naming conventions.

Comment: @user I don't know how to return the values without the constructor, do have an example of your suggestion?

Comment: If the variables are public you can access them without using a get method, otherwise you'll have to use a method to get the values. If you don't need to change the values ever, you can just initialize the object with correct values.

Comment: @user oh I see, that won't work for me because I will be calling the method several times with different values as arguments

Comment: You don't need the constructor then, you can just use a set method to change the variable values, which is basically what your create method does, except it also creates a new object, which is not neccessary to change the values.

Comment: @user but how will I write that without a constructor?

Comment: public class MyClass 
{
    String desc;
    int id;
    public void set(int id, String desc)
    {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass();
        mc.set(0, "somestring");
    }
}

Hard to make it look good in these comments.

Comment: Would that MyClass class not require a return function for each variable being returned? I will update question to show you what I mean

Comment: Trent: You say you are using Informix-4gl with Java.  You don't mention Genero but are you using the Genero Java Interface to use Java inside Informix-4gl? http://www.4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/#c_fgl_JavaBridge_001.html

Comment: @fourjs.reuben Awesome to meet another Genero developer, I'm developing the two programs separately so the Java code is completely standalone, I'm not interfacing with the Java code directly (never actually knew I could do that)

Comment: @Trent there is plenty of us out there.  One thing I encourage Genero developers to do is to periodically read the New Features section of the documentation http://www.4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/?path=fjs-fgl-manual#c_fgl_nf.html.  Tend to find Genero developers aren't aware of all the features we have added over the years which will help with their Genero programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use HashMap<String, Object>

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Object> person =
            new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        // add elements dynamically
        person.put("name", "Lem");
        person.put("age", 46);
        person.put("gender", 'M');

        // prints the name value
        System.out.println(person.get("name")); 
       
        // asures that age element is of integer type before  
        // printing
        System.out.println((int)person.get("age"));
        
        // prints the gender value
        System.out.println(person.get("gender"));
       
        // prints the person object {gender=M, name=Lem, age=46}
        System.out.println(person); 
    }
}
```

The advantage of doing this is that you can add elements as you go.
The downside of this is that you will lose type safety like in the case of the **age**. Making sure that **age** is always an integer has a cost. So to avoid this cost just use a class.

Comment: In this example, an HashMap would be preferable over an Hashtable. Hashtable is synchronized, where HashMap is not. And the preferred way to obtain a synchronized map is no longer to use an Hashtable, but rather call Collections.synchronizedMap with the (unsychronized) implementation you want in parameter. Hashtable should be considered more or less deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm a Java refresher.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such a feature,  you have to type out the full type name(class name).

Or use may use **val** :

https://projectlombok.org/features/val.html

Also, if you use IntelliJ IDEA
try this plugin :

https://bitbucket.org/balpha/varsity/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's possible with Java. `Class` is the primitive structure to generate `Object`. We need a Class to generate object. So, for the above code, i don't think there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Java methods only allow one return value. If you want to return multiple objects/values consider returning one of the collections. Map, List, Queue, etc.

The one you choose will depend on your needs. For example, if you want to store your values as key-value pairs use a Map. If you just want to store values sequentially, use a list.

An example with a list:

```
list<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
myList.add("Some value");
return myList;
```

As a side note, your method create is redundant. You should use getters and setters to populate the object, or populate it through the constructor.

```
cl_Object   lo_Object   = new cl_Object(1, "test01");
```

The way you have it set up right now, you're creating one object to create another of the same type that has the values you want.

Your naming convention is also wrong. Please refer to Java standard naming convention:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: Just to fix the redundancy how would I write that create method differently, do you have an example?

Comment: create is setting the values for another object of the same type. By that I mean your first cl_Object is creating another cl_Object that has the values you want. You can set the values in the constructor when you instantiate the object. When you create your object instead of passing in 0 and null into the constructor pass in "1" and "test01". Inspect the object afterwards and you'll see it has those values set. Also look up the getter and setter convention in java. It is a standard for setting attributes used in conjunction with constructors. You may also want to look at access modifiers :).